# Is it possible to add an entry to a Javascript object residing in an another file?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of JS objects like this in a file called `expenses.js`

```
var expenses = 
[
  {
    day: "9/11/2019", expenses: {
        pen: 15,
        tea: 32,
        auto: 40,
        juice: 30,
    }
  },
  {
    day: "10/11/2019", expenses: {
        bananas: 50,
        auto: 100,
        tea: 30,
    }
  }
]
```

Is is possible to have a function like `addExpenses({day: "11/11/2019", expenses: {biscuit: 20})` in another JS file, called `add-expense.js`, that would add an object to the array of objects in `expenses.js`?

Comment: How is it possible?

Comment: You can use modules for that

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "add".  If you mean at *run-time*, and the function you are executing loads after the file containing the object you want to modify, then the answer is yes, though I don't think you need an `addExpenses` function but could rather just do the following:

```
expenses.push({day: "11/11/2019", expenses: {biscuit: 20});
```

But if by "add" you mean such that the entry is saved to the original file *on-disk*, then the answer is typically no, not in a browser context, though possibly in a node.js context

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using imports and exports. With the little information provided, i created a little rough example to show you how exporting and importing works.

```
    var expenses = 
    [
      {
        day: "9/11/2019", expenses: {
            pen: 15,
            tea: 32,
            auto: 40,
            juice: 30,
        }
      },
      {
        day: "10/11/2019", expenses: {
            bananas: 50,
            auto: 100,
            tea: 30,
        }
      }
    ]

module.exports = expenses;
```

In your add-expenses file :

```
var expenses = require('dir/yourfile')
```

Now you have access to your object in whatever file you wish

Comment: I have understood your solution, but I am using `live server` plugin of VS code. Do I have to run a node server instead?

Comment: @Harish you dont need a server for as far as i am concerned. Most modern browsers support this function.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on the browser platform. It gives a "module is not defined" error. I will try to port my application to node.js platform to make this work.

Comment: yeah , i wasnt entirely sure. But with node it should work 100%

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it on different files but something like this should work

Basically you create a function who accept an array and a value as params.  In the main file you specify your array, `expenses` and the value you want to insert. To be sure that your array is ok and you don't insert wrong data, you can make a little validation on the object that you want to insert

```
// ------- expenses.js ------------

// import add-expense.js
const add = require('./add-expense'); 

var expenses = 
[
  {
    day: "9/11/2019", expenses: {
        pen: 15,
        tea: 32,
        auto: 40,
        juice: 30,
    }
  },
  {
    day: "10/11/2019", expenses: {
        bananas: 50,
        auto: 100,
        tea: 30,
    }
  }
]

let newExpense = {day: "11/11/2019", expenses: {biscuit: 20}}
add.addExpenses(expenses, newExpense)
console.log(expenses)



// ---------  add-expense.js -------------
module.exports = {

  addExpenses: function(myArr, value){
    if(isObjectCorrect(value)){
      myArr.push(value);
    }
  },

  isObjectCorrect: function(value) {
      try {
          JSON.stringify(value);
      } catch (e) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

}
```